# Merge 3 flat, indexed arrays into one flat, indexed array

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I'd like to merge three arrays like this:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4);
$b = array(5,6,7,8);
$c = array(1,2,3,4);
```

into one big array so that the output would be:

```
$result = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4);
$b = array(5,6,7,8);
$c = array(1,2,3,4);

$out = array_merge($a, $b, $c);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 2
    [10] => 3
    [11] => 4
)
```