# Pad short input arrays with their last element value to ensure equal lengths and transpose arrays into one array

Tags: php, arrays, transpose

I have the following Arrays:

```
$front = array("front_first","front_second");
$inside = array("inside_first", "inside_second", "inside_third");
$back = array("back_first", "back_second", "back_third","back_fourth");
```

what I need to do is combine it so that an output would look like this for the above situation.  The output order is always to put them in order `back, front, inside`:

```
$final = array(
"back_first",
"front_first",
"inside_first",
"back_second",
"front_second",
"inside_second",
"back_third",
"front_second",
"inside_third",
"back_fourth",
"front_second",
"inside_third"
);
```

So basically it looks at the three arrays, and whichever array has less values it will reuse the last value multiple times until it loops through the remaining keys in the longer arrays.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: see: [array_merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034521/php-combine-arrays-into-one-big-array)

Comment: You would use array_map() http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: You have forgotten to write where *exaclty* you got stumped, because from the description you give it's pretty clear that you know how to solve this. So your question is not clear.

Comment: E.g. post-fix the arrays with their last value ([`end`](http://php.net/end)) based on [`max`](http://php.net/max)imum [`count`](http://php.net/count), then re-order the array like in [PHP - how to flip the rows and columns of a 2D array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2221476/367456).

Answer (score 3):

```
$front = array("front_first","front_second");
$inside = array("inside_first", "inside_second", "inside_third");
$back = array("back_first", "back_second", "back_third","back_fourth");

function foo() {
  $args = func_get_args();
  $max = max(array_map('sizeof', $args)); // credits to hakre ;)
  $result = array();

  for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i += 1) {
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
      $result[] = isset($arg[$i]) ? $arg[$i] : end($arg); 
    }    
  }

  return $result;
}

$final = foo($back, $front, $inside);
print_r($final);
```

demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/RFmGYW

Comment: Yep. Yours is 60% faster than mine below.

Comment: I keep getting an error on the line where you set `$max` "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'"

Comment: @thindery That's probably because you're using a php version which does not support [inline functions](http://php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php).

Answer (score 2):

**Demo**

http://codepad.viper-7.com/xpwGha

**PHP**

```
$front = array("front_first", "front_second");
$inside = array("inside_first", "inside_second", "inside_third");
$back = array("back_first", "back_second", "back_third", "back_fourth");

$combined = array_map("callback", $back, $front, $inside);

$lastf = "";
$lasti = "";
$lastb = "";

function callback($arrb, $arrf, $arri) {
    global $lastf, $lasti, $lastb;

    $lastf = isset($arrf) ? $arrf : $lastf;
    $lasti = isset($arri) ? $arri : $lasti;
    $lastb = isset($arrb) ? $arrb : $lastb;

    return array($lastb, $lastf, $lasti);
}

$final = array();

foreach ($combined as $k => $v) {
    $final = array_merge($final, $v);
}

print_r($final);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => back_first
    [1] => front_first
    [2] => inside_first
    [3] => back_second
    [4] => front_second
    [5] => inside_second
    [6] => back_third
    [7] => front_second
    [8] => inside_third
    [9] => back_fourth
    [10] => front_second
    [11] => inside_third
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Spreading the column data from multiple arrays with `array_map()` is an easy/convenient way to tranpose data.  It will pass a full array of elements from the input arrays and maintain value position by assigning `null` values where elements were missing.

Within the custom callback, declare a `static` cache of the previously transposed row.  Iterate the new transposed row of data and replace any null values with the previous rows respective element.

After transposing the data, call `array_merge(...$the_transposed_data)` to flatten the results.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eTVZ3))

```
$front = ["front_first", "front_second"];
$inside = ["inside_first", "inside_second", "inside_third"];
$back = ["back_first", "back_second", "back_third", "back_fourth"];

var_export(
    array_merge(
        ...array_map(
            function(...$cols) {
                static $lastSet;
                foreach ($cols as $i => &$v) {
                    $v ??= $lastSet[$i];
                }
                $lastSet = $cols;
                return $cols;
            },
            $back,
            $front,
            $inside
        )
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'back_first',
  1 => 'front_first',
  2 => 'inside_first',
  3 => 'back_second',
  4 => 'front_second',
  5 => 'inside_second',
  6 => 'back_third',
  7 => 'front_second',
  8 => 'inside_third',
  9 => 'back_fourth',
  10 => 'front_second',
  11 => 'inside_third',
)
```