# Merging 2 Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combing 3 arrays into one array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381139/combing-3-arrays-into-one-array)

I have the following arrays:

```
$front = array("front_first","front_second");
$back = array("back_first", "back_second", "back_third","back_fourth");
```

what I'm trying to do is merge them so an output like this would result:

```
$final = array(
    "back_first",
    "front_first",
    "back_second",
    "front_second",
    "back_third",
    "front_second",
    "back_fourth",
    "front_second"
);
```

How can I have it repeat the last value in the shortest array so that it can combine into one `$final[]` with no empty values?.

Answer (score 0):

php's [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$final = array_merge($front, $back);
```

and maybe a combination with [array_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php)?

```
$front = array_pad($front, count($back)-1, 'second_front');
 $final = array_merge($front, $back);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first bit is easy, just use [array_merge()](http://www.php.net/array_merge) to construct your combined array.

The second bit requires arbitrary sorting and therefore will require use of [usort()](http://www.php.net/usort) to sort the array according to rules you implement in the callback function.

Is the order really important?

Comment: yes the orderis important.

Answer (score 0):

Working [Codepad](http://codepad.org/bgIYz9iw) - [bgIYz9iw](http://codepad.org/bgIYz9iw)

```
$final = array();
for( $i = 0; $i < 4; $i++ ) {
  if( $i > 1 ) {
    $final[] = $back[$i];
    $final[] = $front[1];
  }
  else {
    $final[] = $back[$i];
    $final[] = $front[$i];
  }
}
```