# Multiple mysqli select with json

Tags: php, mysql, json, select

```
<?php
include"../database_conn.php";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","123456","ayurveadic");

$query_pag_data = "SELECT id from diseases";
$result_pag_data = mysql_query($query_pag_data) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {
    $diseases_id = $row['id'];

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT $diseases_id FROM treatment WHERE gender_id = '10' AND diseases_id = '$diseases_id'");
    $row_gid = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if ($row_gid == TRUE){

        $sl_dise = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Diseases_type, id FROM diseases WHERE id = '$diseases_id'");

        $rowss = array();
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sl_dise)) {
            $rowss[] = $r;
        }
        print json_encode($rowss);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
[{"Diseases_type":"fever","id":"114"}][{"Diseases_type":"rhrh","id":"123"}]
```

How can i get this output:

```
[{"Diseases_type":"fever","id":"114"},{"Diseases_type":"rhrh","id":"123"}]
```

Comment: Why you are mixing both **mysql_** and **mysqli_**. Always preferred to **mysqli_**, because **mysql_** is deprecated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP combine arrays into one big array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034521/php-combine-arrays-into-one-big-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the JSON array before the outer loop, and print it at the very end, not each time through.

```
<?php
include"../database_conn.php";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","123456","ayurveadic");

$query_pag_data = "SELECT id from diseases";
$result_pag_data = mysql_query($query_pag_data) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());

$rowss = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {
    $diseases_id = $row['id'];

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT $diseases_id FROM treatment WHERE gender_id = '10' AND diseases_id = '$diseases_id'");
    $row_gid = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if ($row_gid == TRUE){

        $sl_dise = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Diseases_type, id FROM diseases WHERE id = '$diseases_id'");

        while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sl_dise)) {
            $rowss[] = $r;
        }
    }
}
print json_encode($rowss);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is you optimised code

```
<?php
include"../database_conn.php";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","123456","ayurveadic");

 $query_pag_data = "select diseases.Diseases_type,diseases.id from diseases inner join treatment on treatment.diseases_id = diseases.id where treatment.gender_id = '10' ";
$result_pag_data = mysql_query($query_pag_data) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());

$rowss = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_pag_data)) {
    $rowss[] = $row;
}
print json_encode($rowss);
?>
```

Comment: Why did you replace `SELECT Diseases_type, id` with `SELECT *`? We should encourage people to select specific columns.

Comment: @Barmar ok. agreed and updated code . but why down vote?

Comment: I didn't downvote. I initially upvoted, then undid it until you fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Put your

```
print json_encode($rowss);
```

after end of this`while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {`

Also remove this `$rowss = array();` array initialization

Comment: That's not all he needs to change, because he's reinitializing `$rowss` each time through the loop.