# Combine multi array to one array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array like the following one and I would like to combine a multi array to one array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ADB_DW2017
    [1] => LM9
    [2] => MS_OF2013
)
Array
(
    [0] => NK
    [1] => PV
    [2] => NK
)
Array
(
    [0] => 15
    [1] => 25
    [2] => 10
)
Array
(
    [0] => 250
    [1] => 111
    [2] => 150
)
Array
(
    [0] => 450
    [1] => 123
    [2] => 250
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => Mien thue
    [2] => 5
)
Array
(
    [0] => 200
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 100
)
Array
(
    [0] => 6.750
    [1] => 3.075
    [2] => 2.500
)
```

I want to combine like this, with the highest performance :

```
Array
(
[ADB_DW2017]=>array([suppiler]=>NK 
                    [min_pro]=>15 
                    [max_pro]=>250 
                    [avg_pro]=>450 
                    [tax]=>0 
                    [com]=>200 
                    [sum]=>6.750
               )
)
```

**My question is :** How to combine a multi array to one array in PHP with the highest performance ?

Comment: Is it possible to give process to generating these arrays? So we can set your desire output at the time of generation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP combine arrays into one big array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034521/php-combine-arrays-into-one-big-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume array names are `$first_array,$second_array,......` (so change varabile names accordingly).

Do like below:-

```
$final_array = array();
foreach ($first_array as $key=> $arr){
   $final_array[$arr] =array(
        'suppiler'=>(isset($second_array[$key]))? $second_array[$key]: '',
        'min_pro'=>(isset($third_array[$key]))? $third_array[$key]: 0,
        'max_pro'=>(isset($fourth_array[$key]))? $fourth_array[$key]: 0,
        'avg_pro'=>(isset($fifth_array[$key]))? $fifth_array[$key]: 0,
        'tax'=>(isset($sixth_array[$key]))? $sixth_array[$key]: '',
        'com'=>(isset($seventh_array[$key]))? $seventh_array[$key]: 0,
        'sum'=>(isset($eigth_array[$key]))? $eigth_array[$key]: 0
    );
}
echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_array);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/829938